# Uploadify & CakePHP 2.1

Tags: php, cakephp, upload, uploadify, cakephp-2.1

I'm now trying to implement Uploadify into my app for about 3 days.
I guess i saw every tutorial which is on the internet...

The only one i found for CakePHP 2.1 was this one: http://crazylearner.com/using-uploadify-with-cakephp/
But this is not working for me :(

I read in some forums that i should be very easy to implement Uploadify. Why is it so complicated for me?

I couldn't find any tutorial which is absolute clear.

Can someone post a working and clear description of how to implement Uploadify in CakePHP 2.1?

thanks, luca

Comment: enable the uploadify debuger (check documentation on how to do that) and check the response and if you are getting blackholed (or 404 error). This is what I was struggling today. If this is the case try deactivate the Security component and see what results you get. Also if you are behind a authetication you have to pass the sessions in your beforeFilter callback.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one, works very nice and is for version 2.1 ok:
https://github.com/josegonzalez/upload

Comment: Does it support multi-upload?